# "org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.expression.SqmCaseSimple does not define or inherit an implementation..." when using SimpleCase but not when using Case?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

I'm getting the error in the title when I am trying to do the following:

```java
CriteriaBuilder.SimpleCase<Integer, String> simpleCase = stringList.stream().reduce(
  criteriaBuilder.selectCase(criteriaBuilder.function("LEAST", Integer.class, expressionMap.values.toArray(Expression[]::new))),
  (caseBuilder, expressionKey) -> caseBuilder.when(
    expressionMap.get(expressionKey),
    expressionKey
  ),
  (previousCaseBuilder, nextCaseBuilder) -> previousCaseBuilder
);
```

However, if I use a `Case` instead of `SimpleCase`, it works fine:

```java
CriteriaBuilder.Case<String> case = stringList.stream().reduce(
  criteriaBuilder.selectCase(),
  (caseBuilder, expressionKey) -> caseBuilder.when(
    criteriaBuilder.equal(
      criteriaBuilder.function("LEAST", Integer.class, expressionMap.values.toArray(Expression[]::new)),
      expressionMap.get(expressionKey)
    ),
    expressionKey
  ),
  (previousCaseBuilder, nextCaseBuilder) -> previousCaseBuilder
);
```

The error I get is the following:

> Receiver class org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.expression.SqmCaseSimple does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract jakarta.persistance.criteria.criteriaBuilder$SimpleCase when(jakarta.persistance.criteria.Expression, jakarta.persistance.criteria.Expression)' of interface jakarta.persistance.criteria.criteriaBuilder$SimpleCase.

When I check the method, everything looks fine. Even the IDE doesn't complain ([see docs](https://javadoc.io/doc/jakarta.persistence/jakarta.persistence-api/3.1.0-RC1/jakarta.persistence/jakarta/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#selectCase(jakarta.persistence.criteria.Expression))):

```java
/**
* Interface used to build simple case expressions.
* Case conditions are evaluated in the order in which
* they are specified.
*/
public static interface SimpleCase<C,R> extends Expression<R> {
/**
* Return the expression to be tested against the
* conditions.
* @return expression
*/
Expression<C> getExpression();
/**
* Add a when/then clause to the case expression.
* @param condition "when" condition
* @param result "then" result value
* @return simple case expression
*/
SimpleCase<C, R> when(C condition, R result);
/**
* Add a when/then clause to the case expression.
* @param condition "when" condition
* @param result "then" result expression
* @return simple case expression
*/
SimpleCase<C, R> when(C condition, Expression<? extends R> result);
/**
* Add an "else" clause to the case expression.
* @param result "else" result
6.3. Criteria API Interfaces
Jakarta Persistence 281
* @return expression
*/
Expression<R> otherwise(R result);
/**
* Add an "else" clause to the case expression.
* @param result "else" result expression
* @return expression
*/
Expression<R> otherwise(Expression<? extends R> result);
}
/**
* Create a simple case expression.
* @param expression to be tested against the case conditions
* @return simple case expression
*/
<C, R> SimpleCase<C,R> selectCase(Expression<? extends C> expression);
```